# I am trying to build a escrow smart contact between club promoter who wants to book my artist with ether but I am getting ParserError

Tags: smartcontracts, escrow

The error I am getting when I compile is: (ParserError: Expected primary expression.price = _price; * (1 ether);)

I would like to add a timestamp of 7 days for the promoter to add all funds to escrow in full not half to meet my conditions to book us. Is this even possible as a condition for us on our in? Do I need a multisig added to my smart contract to make it secure on both sides or is this code ok? Can anyone assist me in solving this problem?

//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.7.6;

contract Escrow {

```
    //VARIBALES
    enum State { NOT_INITIATED, AWAITING_PAYMENT, AWAITING_DELIVERY, COMPLETE }

    State public currState;

    bool public isBuyerIn;
    bool public isSellerIn;

    uint public price;

    address public buyer;
    address  payable public seller;

    //MODIFIERS
    modifier onlyBuyer() {
        require(msg.sender == buyer, "Only buyer can call this function"); _;
    }
    
    modifier escrowNotStarted() {
        require(currState == State.NOT_INITIATED);
        _;

    }

    //FUCTIONS
    constructor(address _buyer, address payable _seller, uint _price){
        buyer =_buyer;
        seller = _seller;
        price = _price; * (1 ether);     
    }

    function initContract() escrowNotStarted public{
        if(msg.sender == buyer) {
            isBuyerIn = true;
        }
        if (msg.sender == seller) {
            isSellerIn = true;
        }
        if (isBuyerIn && isSellerIn) {
            currState = State.AWAITING_PAYMENT;
        }
    }

    function deposit() onlyBuyer public payable {
        require(currState == State.AWAITING_PAYMENT, "Already paiid");
        require(msg.value == price, "Wrong deposit amount");
        currState = State.AWAITING_DELIVERY;
    
    }
    
    function confimDelivery() onlyBuyer payable public {
        require(currState == State.AWAITING_DELIVERY, "Cannot confirm delivery");
        seller.transfer(price);
        currState = State.COMPLETE;
    }

    function withdraw() onlyBuyer payable public {
        require(currState == State.AWAITING_DELIVERY, "Cannot withdraw at this stage");
        payable(msg.sender).transfer(price);
        currState = State.COMPLETE;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra semicolon on the `price` assigning line in the `constructor`.

Replace

```
// original code, extra semicolon
price = _price; * (1 ether);
```

with

```
// updated code, removed the semicolon
price = _price * (1 ether);
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you think you will be able to assist me with the rest of the problems I was attempting to solve with my contract?